# Slick Transactions

Tags: java, scala, slick

Could anyone suggest if we can use transaction on just read operations in slick?
I see that we can your transactionally but is it useful if we use it just for multiple fetch or read operations

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a short answer to this, but yes, using a transaction will often guarantee a more consistent view of the data in your database. This depends on the [isolation level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Isolation_levels) of your underlying database.